# Broadcast to 2 running activities within an application

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 activities running. Activity A is started first followed by Activity B. (ie A in stack, B in focus). I have `BroadcastReceiver` running on both activities. The problem is only Activity A is able to capture my broadcast messages (using `sendBroadcast`)

Why is this so? How can I enable both activities to receive the broadcast without terminating (calling `finish` on Activity A)

Also, is there any way I can reuse the Broadcast receiver method in Activity A?

Broadcast Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MESSAGE_UPDATE);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Activity A

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(resumeHasRun==false){
    IntentFilter movementFilter;
    movementFilter = new IntentFilter();

    movementFilter.addAction(NewService.MESSAGE_UPDATE);

    registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, movementFilter);
    resumeHasRun=true;
    return;
    }
}
public BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    updateTable(message);


    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
}

public void startNewActivity(){
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(newIntent);
    //never call finish
}
```

Activity B

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(resumeHasRun==false){
    IntentFilter movementFilter;
    movementFilter = new IntentFilter();

    movementFilter.addAction(NewService.MESSAGE_UPDATE);

    registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, movementFilter);
    resumeHasRun=true;
    return;
    }
}
public BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    updateAnotherTable(message);


    }
};
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
}
```

Comment: "I have 2 activities running." o'really?

Comment: no it's not http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I have clarified in my post how 2 activities are "running"

Comment: @Selvin you are right. The activity is "running the the background" as it still receives the broadcast intent. Not sure if the way i phrased it is correct.

Comment: Where is the code that you use to hook up the receivers?

Comment: @ZXingIT you only use this for update? or to interact with UI too ? in first case ... move both recivers to one service ... in second ... do the same ... but build contentprovider and use registerContentObserver

Comment: @Sherif I have no receiver method linked to Activity A and B. All set programmatically

Comment: @Selvin `updateTable` method is for handling UI interactions

Comment: @ZXingIT brianestey's comments is very importent, if you do this in usual way (register in onResume and unregister in onPause) this is the cause of recivers behevior

Comment: @Selvin thanks for the comment. I left out some code in my post. Have added them in. I registered them in onResume

Comment: @sherif: alive does not mean running

Comment: Is there any way that resumeHasRun is true when onResume is called in Activity B?  Why do you have this boolean in the first place?

Comment: Initially I am using onResume, this has caused the problem of the receiver registering again. The boolean to to stop it from running after it has started so it only runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move:

```
registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, movementFilter); to onStart()
unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver); to onStop()
```

Make (in its own file):

```
public class TableUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public interface Listener {
       public void tableUpdate(String message);
    };
    Listener mListener;

    public TableUpdateReceiver(Listener list) {
         mListener = list;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.tableUpdate(message);  
        } 
    }
};
```

Make your activities implement TableUpdateReceiver.Listener and:

```
public BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver;
onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
   ...
   mIntentReceiver = new TableUpdateReceiver(this);
   ...
}

public void tableUpdate(String message) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: so where are changes(whitout adding next abstraction level)?

Comment: Thanks this is useful. It works in Activity B but when i end the activity and return to Activity A, the BroadcastReceiver stops working and is giving the error the receiver is not registered.

Comment: When you said that it is possible to run two activities at once, what did you mean? Do you mean that A is still in the stack but B is in focus (A can or cannot be seen behind B?), or A&B are running simultaneously using an ActivityGroup or something?

Comment: Also, do you still have resumeHasRun around the registerReceiver call? you can get rid of it if you're matching registerReceiver and unregisterReceiver correctly (or reset the value to false in onStop)

Comment: Yup i meant A in the  stack. B in focus

Comment: Thanks! I realised resumeHasRun was causing the problem of unregistered receiver error.

Comment: Then moving the register & unregister to onStart/onStop, and removing the resumeHasRun should re-register the receiver when A gets restarted (becomes visible on the screen). However, rereading your question I'm guessing you don't want this as it stops A receiving whilst B is active. In which case put them in onCreate and onDestroy instead.

Comment: when A is in stack, will onStop be called? I have removed resumeHasRun. Have tried with ( A in stack, active B ), (end B with A active), (start B again with A in stack). All are running fine. I have also removed onDestroy as it causes the error too. I guess your original method works. Now, I am going to try with 3 activities, 2 in stack.

Comment: onStop for Activity A will be called when A is no longer visible on the screen (onPause will be called when it is no longer the main focused Activity - for example a dialogue activity will take focus, but doesn't take up all the screen space).

Answer (score 1):

see [this example](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call) it will help you in your problem. Register in both activity and make abstract class activity.

Comment: he don't wana close activity, i think that he is asking why activity, which is not at the top of activity's stack, not recive broadcast ... anway, i think, if this is a normal android behavior this code should not work too

Comment: i posted link because i hv tried sample and activity on top in stack receive broadcast so he can just look code not finish the activity